# Add leading (zeros) , depends on the length of the cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to add leading zeros, depends on the length of cell, 
If Len(cell) = 1 then adds two zeros 00 
If Len(cell) = 2 then adds one zeros 0 
If Len(cell) = 3 then keep as it is 
I tried this formula, but it does not work correctly:

```
=IF(LEN(G2)=1,"00"&G2,LEN(G2)=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try any one of the following:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=TEXT(A2,"000")
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=BASE(A2,10,3)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=BASE(A2:A4,10,MAX(LEN(A2:A4)))
```

---

Comment: Can you still calculate with your formatted result?

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, no but sir OP specifically wants them as leading `0`s

Comment: Here is spilling `TEXT` idea: `=LET(data,A2:A4,TEXT(data,REPT("0",MAX(LEN(data)))))`. Nice catch with `BASE`. Totally forgot about its existence.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir nice trick with `REPT()`

Comment: Also, your results can easily be calculated with as long as you don't add any letters, calculation on a number as text isn't an issue.

Comment: @Notus_Panda yeah agree.

Answer (score 2):

Or just format like this:

[image]

Used a custom format AND this still allows normal calculation as the results are numbers not some form of text.

Showing subsequent calculation:

[image]

Comment: Sir, custom formatting is a nice option, but it is `facade` since the underlying cells will still show as `1` and not as `001`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya the cells C1 to C3 show the values as 001 etc not some "underlying facade"...

Comment: Sir the cells do show as with leading zeros but the underlying cells are `1` etc. its `facade` custom formatting facade, sir dont mind but it is true, if OP wants to a lookup on a value which has leading `0` then custom formatting will not work. Sir here please read. **[Custom formatting is facade](https://www.mrexcel.com/excel-tips/formatting-as-facade/#:~:text=You%20can%20extend%20this%20by%20making%20all%20zones,hidden%20even%20if%20people%20change%20the%20fill%20color.)**

Comment: Sir but i am not saying you are wrong, your answer is correct and will work if OP wants to make any calculations, but adding leading zeros have different requirements.